# Add hypen in sentences where the line breaks in react native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

So I am getting some text messages from backend, and I am showing this text in following manner:

```
<Text
  style={{
    fontSize: 14,
    width: 70,
  }}
  numberOfLines={2}
  >
    {textFromApi}
</Text>
```

So if text is large then it goes to 2nd line. But I want to add a hyphen (-) at the point where word breaks to next line. I know there is something like `hyphens: auto;` for web, but is there something which can be done in react native?

Comment: Try setting [android_hyphenationfrequency](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#android_hyphenationfrequency-android) prop

Answer (score 0):

Not built in but there is package you can use called Hypher:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/hypher

Use it so:

```
import Hypher from 'hypher';
import english from 'hyphenation.en-us';

const h = new Hypher(english);

<Text>
  {h.hyphenateText("Hyphenation")}
</Text>
```

Comment: this is not working